# AJAX returning whole Javascript code instead of the actual data

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

AJAX is returning the whole html page on success instead of the actual data.

Here is the JS code -

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: '**********', status: true, cookie: true,xfbml: true});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(o) { 
if (!o && o.status) return;
if (o.status == 'connected') {
document.write("<php echo "connected" ?>");
} else if (o.status == 'not_authorized') {
document.write("<?php echo "unauthorized" ?>");
} else {
document.write("<php echo "loggedOut" ?>");
} 
});
 };

(function() {
 var e = document.createElement('script'); 
e.async = true;e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

What I need is just the data which is being printed on the page e.g. "connected", "unauthorized","loggedOut".

Comment: Why are you using php echo() for connected/authorized/loggedOut?

Comment: The same problem is persisting even after removing php echo

Comment: `<php` is a syntax error, and the whole php in there is utterly useless. You've also forgotten the `:` in the url you're building. it's going to be `http//connect`, which is NOT going to work.